# Oracle get distinct in xmlagg function

Tags: sql, json, xml, oracle, subquery

I need to get distinct in xmlagg function. For example next query

```sql
select
       xmlagg(xmlelement(e, names.name || ' ')).extract('//text()').getclobval()
           within group (order by names.name ) names,
       xmlagg(xmlelement(e, actions.action || ' ')).extract('//text()').getclobval()
           within group ( order by actions.action) actions
from
json_table('[{"name": "Name1"}, {"name": "Name2"}, {"name": "Name3"}]', '$[*]'
                    columns (name varchar2 path '$.name')) names,
json_table('[{"action": "Call"}, {"action": "Write"}, {"action": "Write"}]', '$[*]'
                    columns (action varchar2 path '$.action')) actions
```

returns

```sh
NAMES                                                 | ACTIONS
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name1 Name1 Name1 Name2 Name2 Name2 Name3 Name3 Name3 | Call Write Write Call Write Write Call Write Write
```

I need to get result like

```sh
NAMES             | ACTIONS
-------------------------------
Name1 Name2 Name3 | Call Write
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is simpler to select the distinct values in a subquery first:

```
select 
    (
        select xmlagg(xmlelement(e, name || ' ') order by name).extract('//text()').getclobval()
        from (
            select distinct name
            from json_table(
                '[{"name": "Name1"}, {"name": "Name2"}, {"name": "Name3"}]', '$[*]'
                columns (name varchar2 path '$.name')
            ) names
        ) n
    ) names,
    (
        select xmlagg(xmlelement(e, action || ' ') order by action).extract('//text()').getclobval()
        from (
            select distinct action
            from json_table(
                '[{"action": "Call"}, {"action": "Write"}, {"action": "Write"}]', '$[*]'
                columns (action varchar2 path '$.action')
            ) actions
        ) a
    ) actions
from dual
```

Note that the `order by` of `xmlagg()` better fits *within* the function.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c5f51b8af7ade79db88fac581786016c)**:

```
NAMES              | ACTIONS    
:----------------- | :----------
Name1 Name2 Name3  | Call Write
```

Comment: 1. within group dows not grouping xmlagg values. It raises exception ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @KamoPetrosyan: I fixed the query, and added a db fiddle to my answer as well.